# PDO ODBC query on linked tables doesn't give any results

Tags: php, sql, ms-access, odbc, linked-tables

I would like to use PDO ODBC to get datas from .mdb file. This works fine when querying on "normal" tables, however it always fails on **linked tables**, whatever the query is.

**Connexion :**

```
$pdo = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$mdb;SystemDB=$mdw;", $user, $pass);
```

**Ex :**

> ```
> A normal table "test" (id, name)
> Query : SELECT * FROM test
> It works, I get the expected rows
>
> A linked table "linked_test"
> Query : SELECT * FROM linked_test
> It doesn't return anything
> ```

But on attached/linked/synchronized tables i can't get any results, the PDOStatement just return the queryString, no result to fetch.

These tables are synchronized to a Oracle Database.

Then the question is how should I proceed to get results from theses tables ?

Thanks.

Sorry for my bad english...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you are attempting simply won't work from PHP. You will need to create a separate connection to the Oracle database and pull the information directly from there.